# Sass source map bug in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, sass

*First, I´m not talking about the auto save to disc function.*

My problem is, that I inspect an element with chrome, change some of the css styles, and after changing even only one of them, the source map stops working and chrome shows only the .css file instead of the .scss files.
After reloading the page, the sass map file is getting loaded properly again.

Doing the same thing with firefox, is working correctly.
So it looks like a chrome bug.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: It's not a bug. You edited the styles and thus the sourcemap was invalidated, it's a feature.